# How and where to use promises in javascript in real time scenario?

Tags: javascript

I am new to "promises" word in javascript, read some articles but unable to understand the logic and where I can use them in real time. Please explain a little bit.

Comment: Sorry, but this is far too broad a question to be answered in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you any way, I was just looking for some link or example from where I can understand this concept.

Comment: @jforjs : Did my post help you?

Answer (score 1):

May be [this](http://www.jscripters.com/javascript-advantages-and-disadvantages/) will help you. client side code are handy when you have the resources in the client browser where in the page does not have to forward a request to server all the time.

Eg: 
Take the example of validation. You need to check if a textbox is given a value or not. To do this we do not need the server code to be invoked since it consumes time and processor of the server. Instead we write a client side code to validate the text box. This will be faster too and does not need the help of server since all the required resources that is required to check the filed is available locally in the client browser.

And again this is a broad topic as commented by Andy so my explanation is just to give you a small idea. Hope the link helps you.

Here is another [link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/90057/why-do-we-still-use-javascript)